# Least Squares Construction

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $L \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a line through the origin, and let
>   **b** $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be any point.
>
> a.) Find a geometrical construction of the closest point **v** $\in L$
>   to **b** when the distance is measured in the standard Euclidean norm.
>
> b.) Use your construction to prove that there is one and only one
>   closest point.
>    c.) Show that if $0 \ne$ **a** $\in L$,  the the
>   distance equals $\frac{\sqrt{||a||^2||b||^2 - (a * b)^2}}{\|a||} =
>  \frac{|a\times b|}{||a||}$.

My attempt:

a.)Let $l_1,l_2$ be a basis for L. Then the general element of $v \in L$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors. Thus, $x_1l_1 + x_2l_2 = Ax$ is the m x n matrix formed by the basis vectors and **x** = $(x_1,x_2)^T$ are the coordinates of **v**. So, the closest point in L to b is $||v-b||^2 = ||Ax - b||^2$ over all possible $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

b.) I do not know how to do this

c.) I do not know how to do this

Comment: If $L$ is a line through the origin of ${\bf R}^2$, then it is one-dimensional, and any basis for it consists of a single vector, not a pair of vectors. You are dealing in colorless green ideas again.

Comment: Thank you a lot Gerry for clearing that up once again! You are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is a projection. You draw a perpendicular $P$ through the line $L$, passing through the point $b$. The closest point is the point on $L$ through which the perpendicular $P$ passes.

(b) By Euclid's axioms (I believe #5), $P$ exists and is unique. It also must intersect $L$ in exactly one place, and so  the resulting projection is unique as well.

(c) use Pythagorean theorem to show the left-hand side.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood your answer for a and b, but not for c. Can you provide more detail on how to construct the proof?

Comment: @diimension The origin, $b$ and the point of projection (say $x$) form a right-angled triangle, where $\vec{x} = k \vec{a}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$, since they lie on the same line. The trick is, what is the value of $k$?

Comment: So since $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar then k = $\frac{\vec{x}}{\vec{a}}$ ?

Comment: @diimension You cannot divide vectors. But you have to compute by how much to scale $\vec{a}$ to get exactly $\vec{x}$. You probably want to use the $\cos$ of the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ to compute $\vec{x}$ (i.e. dot product will come in handy) ...